# React Navigation v6 stack navigator with headerLargeTitle collapsing too fast

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In my app I am trying to use [React Navigation's stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/) with `headerLargeTitle` and `headerTransparent` enabled.

My implementation looks like this:

Navigator.tsx

```
<HomeStack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="ScreenA"
  screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    title: 'My app',
    headerTransparent: true,
    headerBlurEffect: 'light',
    headerLargeTitleShadowVisible: false,
    headerLargeTitle: true,
    headerSearchBarOptions: {
      autoCapitalize: 'none',
      obscureBackground: false,
    },
  })}
>
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name="ScreenA"
    component={ScreenA}
  />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
```

ScreenA returns:

```
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

return (
<>
  {isReady && (
    <ScrollView
      contentInset={{
        top: headerHeight * 2,
      }}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}
    >
      <View.Base
        style={{
          height: 900,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        }}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )}
</>
);
```

This currently produces the following output:

[Video example](https://cleanshot-cloud-fra.accelerator.net/media/8544/6OXRJom9qBJA7RFP6kUsQkvSXjtTwPmxTGC2SwDm.mp4)

As you can see, the header collapses way too fast and I am unable to figure out why, sadly.

When setting `headerTransparent` to false, it has an issue with the collapsing effect to not "snap", so something's off here.

Also, the headerHeight doesn't seem to return the correct height for large title-headers. Not sure of that has something to do with this.

Answer (score 5):

> Also, the headerHeight doesn't seem to return the correct height for large title-headers. Not sure of that has something to do with this.

Yes, the value returned by `useHeaderHeight()` does not seem to take large headers into account.

Both of your issues should be solved by setting the property `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` on the `ScrollView` to `"automatic"`. Like this:

```js
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

return (
  <>
    {isReady && (
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}
      >
        <View.Base
          style={{
            height: 900,
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )}
  </>  
);
```

Comment: Doing this causes my navigation to start with the large header collapsed unless I add a search box to the navigation page.